# как мне исправить код?

Tags: python, telebot

```
elif message.text == "IpAdress":
    Ip = bot.reply_to(message, "Domen")
    
    
    url = 'https://ip-calculator.ru/siteip/?domain=https%3A%2F%2F' + Ip
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    quotes = soup.find_all('div', class_='row')
    for quote in quotes:
        bot.reply_to(message, quote.text)
```

Comment: В редакторе. Можно в IDLE или PyCharm. Вносите изменения, потом сохраняете. Ничего особого не нужно делать, всё просто.

Answer (score -1):

Ну, во-первых, в использовании сторонних сервисов особого смысла нет.

```bsh
~ 
➜ python                                                    
Python 3.10.4 (main, Mar 23 2022, 23:05:40) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run(['dig', '+short', 'fsb.ru'])
213.24.76.23
CompletedProcess(args=['dig', '+short', 'fsb.ru'], returncode=0)
>> import socket
>> socket.getaddrinfo('fsb.ru', 80)
[(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>, 6, '', ('213.24.76.23', 80)), (<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_DGRAM: 2>, 17, '', ('213.24.76.23', 80)), (<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_RAW: 3>, 0, '', ('213.24.76.23', 80))]
>>> socket.getaddrinfo('fsb.ru', 443)
[(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>, 6, '', ('213.24.76.23', 443)), (<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_DGRAM: 2>, 17, '', ('213.24.76.23', 443)), (<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_RAW: 3>, 0, '', ('213.24.76.23', 443))]
>>>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне нужно узнать как зделать в модуле телебот зделать так: adress= input('введите текст'); bot.reply_to(message, adress)